# when a thread is blocked.can cause the blocking of another thread in the same process or the whole process?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, dependencies, block

when a thread is being blocked is it necessary that this thread blocks any other threads in the same process or its process?is this happening every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  We wouldn't have to cope with deadlock if that wasn't the case.  The scenario is that the blocked thread acquired a synchronization object that another thread tries to acquire as well.  It will block.

Okay, I get the question now.  Generally, yes.  Some other code needs to run to release the blocking condition.  The non-obvious cases are kernel threads that run code in drivers if the thread is blocked on I/O.  Or the thread scheduler, in case the thread is blocked because it is waiting to acquire the processor or is waiting with a non-infinite time-out.

Comment: excuse my wrong expression..i didnt mean if that happens or if there is a possibility.i wanted to ask: when a thread is being blocked is it necessary that this thread blocks any other threads in the same process or its process?is this happening every time?

Comment: @user: could you edit your question to include this clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can happen for any synchronization operation, where one thread needs to wait for another thread to do something.  For instance, if thread A holds a lock and then does a long blocking operation in the kernel, another thread B will block if it tries to acquire the lock.  Thread B will be blocked at least until thread A's blocking operation finishes.

In extreme cases, threads waiting on each other will result in [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

**Additional clarification**:

Threads in a process run independently of each other.  One thread blocking shouldn't necessarily block the other threads.  This is one of the main reasons that threads are used in the first place,.

Answer (score -1):

when a thread is blocked , it blocks also all the threads within the process

Comment: No, this is simply not true. Deadlocking happens in cases described in the already-posted answers; it does not happen automatically as you say *at all*.